# AttributeError: 'Overview' object has no attribute '__qualname__'

Tags: django, attributes, python-3.7, wsgi, django-wsgi

I am updating Django from `1.11.27` to `2.2.9` - python2.7 to python3.7 - made all the changes, but when I start server I have this error.

`AttributeError: 'Overview' object has no attribute '__qualname__'`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 213, in inner
    if request.path == reverse('admin:logout', current_app=self.name):
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 58, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 513, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 464, in _populate
    url_pattern._populate()
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 464, in _populate
    url_pattern._populate()
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 452, in _populate
    self._callback_strs.add(url_pattern.lookup_str)
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/user/Sites/project-folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 362, in lookup_str
    return callback.__module__ + "." + callback.__qualname__
AttributeError: 'Overview' object has no attribute '__qualname__'
```

Found the exception here (Django 2.2.9):
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/resolvers.py#L361

```
@cached_property
def lookup_str(self):
    """
    A string that identifies the view (e.g. 'path.to.view_function' or
    'path.to.ClassBasedView').
    """
    callback = self.callback
    if isinstance(callback, functools.partial):
        callback = callback.func
    if not hasattr(callback, '__name__'):
        return callback.__module__ + "." + callback.__class__.__name__
    return callback.__module__ + "." + callback.__qualname__
```

Comment: Do you have a view named "Overview"?

Comment: @IainShelvington I have located a Class named Overview in Mailchimp moduel, so I turned it off and it started working, when I put it back - same errror - it is here (there overview) - https://github.com/python-force/django-mailchimp/blob/master/mailchimp/views.py - not sure what needs to be updated to make that to work with it.

Comment: django-mailchimp has been deprecated in favour of https://pypi.org/project/django-mailchimp-v1.3/

Comment: I know I have forked it and did another adjustments for django 2.2.9 to work - but can't solve that one.

Comment: Try subclassing the built in `django.views.generic.base.View` rather than `mailchimp.utils.BaseView` in the class `MailchimpBaseView`?

Comment: Can you edit this to make it what you mean? https://codeshare.io/alVn6Z

Comment: This looks like the most up to date package for mailchimp https://github.com/VingtCinq/python-mailchimp, there's a blog post here https://blog.theodo.com/2018/01/monkey-see-django-mailchimp-automation-django/

Comment: I am going to update to newest one repo that I found which is fine - but for now I do not have time to do that and code the connections - I need to make this to work 1st to be usable while I'll be developing a new connection with new repo, entire site is already working with everything, this is the last part that I am missing...

Comment: I think the problem is this line https://github.com/python-force/django-mailchimp/blob/master/mailchimp/views.py#L189

Comment: Maybe you could add a method `__qualname__` to the `BaseView` class that returns anything just for now

Comment: Something like this? class MailchimpView(MailchimpBaseView):
    required_permissions = ['mailchimp.can_view']
    
    def __qualname__(self):
        return ""

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if it would mess things up, you may need to return something else if it does

Comment: TypeError: type __qualname__ must be a str, not function

Comment: The exception is here in Django 2.2.9: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/resolvers.py#L361

Comment: @IainShelvington I have ended up installing new and code the connection to MC with the repo you sent over - was faster then fixing the old one :) thank you - all working now